# Comparing button Tag with String in android

Tags: java, android, string, button, compare

I am working on an android project where it needs to get data from database as grid view (contains multiple buttons). I have already done up to that part. Now I need to compare those data with a given string. 
Here, I have tagged the status from the database to the button before put it in to the grid view.

```
holder.btn.setTag(data.get(position).getStatus());
```

the following code has shown that how I am trying to compare those values.

```
    String x = "NA";
    String y = holder.btn.getTag().toString();

    if (x.equals(y)) {
        holder.btn.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

But it is not working. Please Help me to solve this issue.

Additionally, in my database there is a column call status....it contains values such as A and NA (Available and Not Available). I have already got that values from data base and set it to the item objects array list call data. in that item object i have declared field call status and then I have assigned that data base values to that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to print to console both strings? So you can compare them and check by yourself where the error is...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ...yes sir I have printed both of it in the log cat and it's working finely ...but when it put to the condition something going wrong...:(

Comment: Make sure both are uppercase in order to compare. Did you try to check if you can actually get into to the if? Print something if the if becomes true and the you'll know if you are doing a bar comparison or the comparison is ok but the UI is not being updated.

Comment: yes sir both are uppercase...sorry sir I did not get the second part that u have said....you mean just try to print something in the log cat if the condition is true? sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: Exactly. You must be sure where the problem is. If really is the equals or is the GUI not being updated

Comment: Just now I tried it as well...but nothing has printed when the Log cat printing statement in side the condition block ....that means something wrong with the button tag part....

Comment: I mean the problem is contain in the equal part

Comment: What are you seeing as the value of `y` if you try to print it to Logcat directly after you assign it (before the if statement)?

Comment: In my database there is a column call status....it contains values such as A and NA (Available and Not Available). I have already got that values from data base and set it to the item objects array list call data. in that item object i have declared field call status and then I have assigned that data base values to that.

Comment: It is printed finely in the Logcat as NA, A , etc

Answer (score 0):

The method `getTag()` returns an `Object`, not a `String`. So you have to cast it to a `String` when you retrieve it. Try this:

```
String x = "NA";
String y = (String) holder.btn.getTag();

if (x.equals(y)) {
    holder.btn.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Also keep in mind that if you are originally setting the Tag with something other than a String, then you'll have to convert it to a String when you use `getTag()`. So, for example, if your line `holder.btn.setTag(data.get(position).getStatus());` sets an int as the tag, you would have to do `String y = (String) Integer.toString(holder.btn.getTag());` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir. I have already tried that as well... but it gives same output

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is at line if getStatus() returns no string

```
holder.btn.setTag(data.get(position).getStatus());
```

You can try with

```
holder.btn.setTag(data.get(position).getStatus().toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..No sir it returns a string value.. because I have tried the getTag() method in the log cat and its working finely. it was printed in the Log cat

Comment: It is rare. Have you tried with compareTo? 

    if (x.compareTo(y) == 0) { ...

Good luck!